# JProfiler menu in Eclipse plugin disabled

Tags: eclipse, jprofiler

I downloaded the Jprofiler app with the ten-day free license option, and installed the eclipse plugin (for eclipse 4.6.) I added Profile to the visible action sets, and now see the Profile as...etc options under the run menu.

But they are all disabled. I have a class open in eclipse that has a public static void main[] method, but can't find any documentation on what I have to do to enable the profile options in the run menu.

Comment: The profile actions are part of the eclipse infrastructure. If they are disabled, no profiler is installed. Please make sure that you select the  correct eclipse installation directory in the IDE integration setup (Session->IDE integrations)

Comment: I have eclipse neon installed in C:\Users\(username)\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse. The jprofiler plugin was installed into C:\Users\(username)\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse\dropins\com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse .

Comment: If you invoke Help->About Eclipse SDK->Installation Details->Plug-Ins and filter for "jprofiler", do you get any results?